# How can I convert a forloop to Numpy single operation?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to improve calculation speed. I have this code:

```
for index_subsequence in range(number_of_sequences):
     sequence = sequences[index_sequence]
     multiplication = np.multiply(sequence, matrix)
```

Let's use concrete dimensions:

"matrix" has a shape of (2207, 12).

"sequences" has a shape of (1884, 12).
Consequently, "sequence" is a vector is a vector with 12 entries.

np.multiply(sequence, matrix) yields another (2207, 12) matrix, where each row is multiplied with "sequence".

The code works correctly, but I want to get rid of the for loop.

What I need is a new 3D array "multiplications" which has the shape (number_of_sequences, 2207, 12).

```
multiplications[0] = np.multiply(sequences[0], matrix)
multiplications[1] = np.multiply(sequences[1], matrix)
```

Comment: What happens for the range of `1885:2207`? So where there are no `sequences`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it

- one dimension added to seq and matrix to make it 3d
- broadcast rule works as following
- mat2 has 1st dim empty so it will be repeated to match 1st dim of seq2
- seq2 has 2nd dim empty so it will be repeated to match 2nd dim of mat2

```py
import numpy as np

seq = np.eye(3, 3)
matrix = np.arange(4*3).reshape(4,3)

seq2 = seq[:, np.newaxis, :]
mat2 = matrix[np.newaxis, :, :]

result = seq2 * matrix

print(seq)
print(matrix)
print(result)
```

**Result**

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]


[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]


[[[ 0.  0.  0.]
  [ 3.  0.  0.]
  [ 6.  0.  0.]
  [ 9.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  1.  0.]
  [ 0.  4.  0.]
  [ 0.  7.  0.]
  [ 0. 10.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  2.]
  [ 0.  0.  5.]
  [ 0.  0.  8.]
  [ 0.  0. 11.]]]
```